# Is it possible to specify an Expression for a single property selector?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I can specify that a method takes an `Expression<Func<Foo, object>>` as an argument in order to get an api that looks something like this:

```
// With a method declaration like this...
public void Foo(Expression<Func<Bar, object>> selector) { .... }

// ...I can invoke the method like this
Foo(b => b.Baz);
Foo(b => new { b.Baz, b.Foo });
```

However, I am writing an API which would benefit from being able to **only** allow a single property to be chosen. Like this:

```
public void Foo(Expression<Func<Bar, ...>> selector) { .... }

// This would be OK.
Foo(b => b.Baz);

// But this would not...
Foo(b => new { b.Baz, b.Foo });
```

Is there a way to express this to restrict the expressions in this way?

Of course, I could always just document this and check the expressions during runtime, but if possible I would prefer to make an API that doesn't throw RuntimeExceptions if I can avoid it.

Edit:

I guess I could change the return value of the Func in the method declaration to be a specific type and thus restrict the expressions a bit at least. But I'd prefer not to do this since I'd like to be able to accept pretty much any type of property in this method call.

Comment: You should be writing your code such that it will work even if they pass an expression that does something other than just project out to a property.  Whatever code that you have that only works when the expression is nothing but a property access should be re-written to be less fragile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to require, through static checking, that the expression is only a property access of the property of the expression.  You can only ever perform such a check at runtime.

Comment: That's too bad :/ It would be quite cool if you could express concepts like that. I'm attempting to write a DSL, and thus trying to "lock down" what kind of parameters can be passed as much as possible seems to be a good idea to be more user-friendly. Though I guess that I'll just have to settle for less in this case - and write more documentation instead.

Comment: @wasatz [As I said earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399563/is-it-possible-to-specify-an-expression-for-a-single-property-selector/29399684?noredirect=1#comment46975217_29399563), you should write the code using the expression in a way that will allow it to work, even if something other than a single property is passed, if at all possible (and it typically is).

Comment: Sadly it doesn't make much sense in this context. This method invocation will eventually be translated into an external call to another system which requires a single property to have been selected. I could multiplex it into several calls...but I don't really like that kind of behind-the-scenes magic. Though I'll mull it over for a day or two and see if I can figure out a better API design. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a specific parent object for acceptable types, the following would enforce parameters at compile-time

```
public void Foo<TSource, TTarget>(Expression<Func<TSource, TTarget>> selector)
    where TSource : Bar
    where TTarget : Bar
{ ... }
```

Since anonymous types derives from `object`, this will prevent their use, since both `TSource` and `TTarget` must derive from `Bar`

However, this only specifies that the source and result are derived from a specific type - checking what the expression is is, by definition, a runtime check, since you're validating data in an object.

Comment: This would prevent the use of an anonymous type, but it would do nothing to require that the expression be nothing but a projection of the parameter to a property of that parameter.  It could contain anything that resolves to the appropriate type.  That in addition to the fact that the OP has no idea what type the property is going to be when creating this method, so there's no way for him to restrict it to a particular type in the first place.